# waiting for filtered $scope model to update

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm using ng-repeat and setting up a $scope variable with my filtered collection

```
<tr ng-repeat="r in filteredData = (data | filter: {Number: num} | filter: eFilter)">
```

In my controller:

```
        $scope.num = undefined;
        console.log($scope.filteredData.length); //returns 10
        $scope.num = 2
        console.log($scope.filteredData.length); //expecting 5
        $scope.num = undefined;
        console.log($scope.filteredData.length); //expecting 10, however, it  actually      returns 5.
```

If i put a timeout on it, e.g. below, i get the expected 10. I'd rather not use a timeout -- i'm sure there is some angular function i can call, perhaps one that forces the digest loop ? Hoping someone can explain how to properly wait for $scope.filteredData to update to reflect the filter change.

```
        setTimeout(function () { console.log($scope.filteredData.length); }, 1); // returns 10
```

Comment: The angular function you're looking for is `$timeout`; if you use it with a delay of zero it will wait until the next `$digest` (no need for arbitrary extra time on top of that.)

Comment: How so? "Angular's wrapper for window.setTimeout" -- seems to be the same thing i'm doing above

Comment: Pretty much, yeah.  You need to delay something to the next digest, $timeout is the angular way to do that.    The advantage it has over vanilla setTimeout is that it won't break if your $digests take longer than whatever setTimeout delay you use.

Comment: (Alternatively you can force a digest by using $scope.$apply; generally I find it that leads to performance problems but in some cases it may be preferable.)